# How the arguments of $U_3$ gate are converted when they're not lying in the expected range?

Tags: programming, qiskit, mathematics, bloch-sphere

From the qiskit documentation ([here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html#Single-Qubit-Quantum-states)), a general form of a single qubit unitary is defined as
$$
U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -e^{i\lambda} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
e^{i\phi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Where $0≤≤,  0≤<2, \text{and} \  0≤<2$. However, when I tried to put some arguments out of the range, the gate still operates. For example, if I set $\theta = -1,\phi=8,\lambda=7$,

```
simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
quancir = QuantumCircuit(1)  
quancir.u3(-1,8,7,0)
results = execute(quancir, simulator).result()
resvec = results.get_statevector(quancir)
bloch_sphere([conv(resvec)])
```

I can still visualize how the $U_3$ gate operates on the initial state $|0\rangle$, and plot the final vector:
[image]

I'm wondering if my arguments aren't in the expected range, like in this case, what really happened to the $U_3$ gate? Am I still getting the vector I want, or do I need to convert the arguments myself to make sure the output vector is correct? Thanks:)

Update: I tried to take the mod of those parameters but it looks like the output vector is different (points toward the opposite direction):

```
quancir = QuantumCircuit(1)  
T = float(-1%pi)
P = float(8%(2*pi))
L = float(7%(2*pi))
quancir.u3(T,P,L,0)
results = execute(quancir, simulator).result()
resvec = results.get_statevector(quancir)
bloch_sphere([conv(resvec)])
```

[image]

Comment: These are periodic functions. So for instance, $\sin(3) = \sin(3 + 2\pi)$.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks for the comment! I tried to calculate the mod but it looks like the output vector points toward the opposite direction. (I just updated my question)

Comment: If you put $-1 + 2\pi$ then I think you should get the right answer.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks! I tried that for `T` but it's still the same vector on the second picture.

Comment: `quancir = QuantumCircuit(1)  
quancir.u3(-1+2*pi,8 - 2*pi ,7 - 2*pi,0)
resvec =quancir.statevector()
bloch_sphere([resvec])` Try this...

Comment: @KAJ226 This works!! Why do we add 2*pi for theta?

Comment: It is the same as $-1\%(2\pi)$. Note in the function, the factor is $\theta/2$.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks, so all the parameters should `% 2*pi`, right?

Comment: It should be. If you plug in different parameters then you can see it.

Comment: @KAJ226 Thank you so much:)

Comment: @KAJ226 I just realized that `2*pi-1` is still greater than `pi`, which is greater than the range of `theta` . is that what we should expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case all input parameters will be mod $4\pi$, $2\pi$, and $2\pi$ for $\theta$, $\phi$, and $\lambda$ respectively. You will obtain the same vector that you would have received if you took the mod of these parameters yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried that but it turns out that the vector is different (I just updated my question).

Comment: You're right, I have corrected my answer. $\theta$ is $4\pi$ periodic due to its factor of $1/2$ as seen in its matrix representation.